# How to find the highest percentage of GC content including its ID?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm going through a problem on Rosalind that involves outputting the ID of the string with the highest GC content percentage and the percentage and I'm running into an issue. I am able to output the sample data ID + Percentage but I don't know how to find the highest.

```
#!/bin/env python3

import sys

input = input()
file = open(input, "r")
#print(input)

gc = 0
at = 0
unknown = 0

for line in file:
  if line.startswith(">"):
    if (gc + at) > 0:
     total = gc + at
     percentage = float(gc)/float(total) * 100
     result = percentage
     print(seq_id, result)
    seq_id = line.strip()
    gc = at = unknown = 0
  else:
   nuc_str = list(line.strip())
   for n in nuc_str:
    if n == "G" or n == "g" or n == "C" or n == "c":
     gc += 1.0
    elif n == "A" or n == "a" or n == "T" or n == "t":
     at += 1.0
    else:
     unknown += 1.0
total = gc + at
percentage = float(gc)/float(total) * 100
result = percentage
print(seq_id, result)
```

The output that is desired is:

```
Rosalind_0808
60.919540
```

The output I am getting is:

```
>Rosalind_6404 53.75
>Rosalind_5959 53.57142857142857
>Rosalind_0808 60.91954022988506
```

The input file is a sample data fasta file taken from rosalind:

```
>Rosalind_6404
CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGAATAGCCAGAACCGTTTCTCTGAGGCTTCCGGCCTTCCCTCCCACTAATAATTCTGAGG
>Rosalind_5959
CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCAATTAAGTCCCTATCCAGGCGCTCCGCCGAAGGTCTATATCCATTTGTCAGCAGACACGC
>Rosalind_0808
CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGACTGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT
```

I'm trying not to use biopython.

Comment: You should append them to a list or dictionary, and then print out the max, otherwise given the script you'll be always printing every input given.

Comment: okay i will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few optimisations that you can use to make your code better and more succinct. For example, using a `list` of `tuples` you can keep the sequence headers associated with their GC contents.

So your loop would look like:

```
# Create an empty list to collect results
results = []
for line in file:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        if (gc + at) > 0:
            total = gc + at
            percentage = float(gc)/float(total) * 100
            result = percentage
            # Add results to the list here
            results.append((seq_id, result))
            seq_id = line.strip()
            gc = at = unknown = 0
    else:
        nuc_str = list(line.strip())
        for n in nuc_str:
            if n == "G" or n == "g" or n == "C" or n == "c":
                gc += 1.0
            elif n == "A" or n == "a" or n == "T" or n == "t":
                at += 1.0
            else:
                unknown += 1.0
```

After running the loop `results` looks like:

```
[
 ("Rosalind_6404", 53.75), 
 ("Rosalind_5959", 53.57142857142857), 
 ("Rosalind_0808", 60.91954022988506),
]
```

Then, to collect the sequence that has the highest GC content we can use `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
result = max(results, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Using the `key` parameter, we are telling `max` to find the list item that has the highest value at position `1` in the tuples.
`result` looks like this:

```
("Rosalind_0808", 60.91954022988506)
```

To output your result in the format that you need, we can use `format`:

```
 print("{}\n{:.6f}".format(*result))
```

Which outputs:

```
Rosalind_0808
60.919540
```

---

Other optimisations:

- Use a `with` statement to open your file, this has the benefit of closing the file properly after processing
- Count GC, and use the sequence length (from `len`) as the divisor
- Use `lower()` instead of comparing both uppercase and lowercase

I wrote my own version, which looks like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = []
with open("test.fa", "r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] in ">":
            header = line[1:]
            seq = next(fh).strip()
            gc = sum(1 for base in seq if base.lower() in "gc")
            res.append((header, gc / len(seq) * 100))

result = max(res, key=itemgetter(1))
print("{}\n{:.6f}".format(*result))
```